# Explanation for applying Cauchy Integral Formula

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

[image: Problems]

I do not understand the last part.

How do you get:

$$\oint_{C_N} f(z) dz = \frac{-7\pi^3}{45} + 4\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{\coth(n\pi)}{n^3}$$

How do you derive this, and what part of cauchy's formula is this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just as a curiosity, what book is that?

Comment: It is also interesting to prove such identity without the residue theorem.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, I am reading the same book as Anonymous, the book is called Schaum's Outline of Complex Variables

Answer (score 2):

The paragraph above the last part is finding the residues of $f(z)$ at its poles inside $C_N$.  $C_N$ is a simple positively oriented closed contour.  Then you just use the [residue theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) to express the integral around $C_N$ in terms of the sum of those residues.

Actually, there's a factor of $\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}$ that I don't see in the formulas given, but maybe the book is using a definition of $\oint dz$ that takes this into account.  The factor of $4$ comes from the fact that the same residue
$\coth(n\pi)/n^3$ comes from four poles, at $n$, $-n$, $ni$ and $-ni$.

Comment: Myself reading through complex analysis, I would say the question is good. The response is good too. But out of curiosity, how would you get $$\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{\coth(\pi n)}{n^3}$$ This isnt said in the other wikipedia article?

Comment: Also, why is taking the sum of residues required?

Comment: Ultimately, because integration is a linear operation.

Answer (score 2):

You get the result from the residue theorem.  As has been pointed out, the integrand

$$f(z) = \frac{\pi \cot{\pi z} \coth{\pi z}}{z^3} $$

has poles at $z= \pm n$ and $z=\pm i n$, for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.  The poles for $n \ne 0$ are simple, while the pole for $n=0$ has order $5$.

Note that $\lim_{x\to 0} x \cot{x} = 1$.  Thus, the residue for $n \ne 0$ at $z=\pm n$ is

$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z=\pm n} \frac{\pi \cot{\pi z} \coth{\pi z}}{z^3} = \frac{\coth{\pi n}}{n^3} $$

Note also that $\lim_{x\to 0} x \coth{x} = 1$ and $i \cot{i \pi n} = \coth{\pi n}$.  Thus,

$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z= \pm i n} \frac{\pi \cot{\pi z} \coth{\pi z}}{z^3} = \frac{\coth{\pi n}}{n^3} $$

The above explains the sum on the RHS.

The other piece is the residue at $z=0$.  Given that the pole is of order 5, the residue is

$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z= 0} \frac{\pi \cot{\pi z} \coth{\pi z}}{z^3} = \frac{\pi}{4!} \left [\frac{d^4}{dz^4}(z^2\cot{\pi z} \coth{\pi z})  \right ]_{z=0} $$

That is a pretty horrifying calculation.  An easier way is to return to the definition of the residue, which is simply the coefficient of $1/z$ in the Laurent series of $f(z)$.  Now, use the fact that

$$\cot{\pi z} = \frac1{\pi z} \left (1-\frac13 \pi^2 z^2 - \frac1{45} \pi^4 z^4 + O(z^6) \right ) $$
$$\coth{\pi z} = \frac1{\pi z} \left (1+\frac13 \pi^2 z^2 - \frac1{45} \pi^4 z^4 + O(z^6) \right ) $$

Then

$$\frac{\pi \cot{\pi z} \coth{\pi z}}{z^3} = \frac{1}{\pi z^5} \left (1 - \frac{2}{45} \pi^4 z^4 - \frac1{9} \pi^4 z^4 + O(z^6) \right ) $$

The residue is then

$$-\frac{2}{45} \pi^3 - \frac19 \pi^3 = -\frac{7 \pi^3}{45}$$

as shown above.

Comment: Great answer!! But I still cannot see how you got the residue at $z=0$? Can you link me to this method, because the one I know uses limits. Also, how is it $4$ times the sum??

Comment: The $4$ times comes from the fact that the residues are the same for $\pm n$ and $\pm i n$; that is, we are summing along each half of the $x$ and $y$ axes.  As far as the residue is concerned, I just used the definition, which is a lot easier for higher-order poles.

Comment: I see the $4$ times aspect. I dont understand which definition of Residue you are using though.... 

Also, shouldnt the sum be:

$$=4\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\coth(\pi n)}{n^3}$$

Comment: @RonGordon, how did you get that series for $\cot(\pi z)$ and $\coth(\pi z)$??

Comment: @RonGordon, why is taking the sum of residues actually required? Shouldnt it also start from $n=-\infty$